# Xamarin Forms Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, auth0

I'm using Auth0 with Xamarin Forms PCL Library.
I have following MainPage class :

```
namespace LoginPattern
{
    public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainPage ()
        {
            Master = new MenuPage ();
            Detail = new DetailPage ();
        }
    }
}
```

And following in Application class

```
public App ()
{   
    Current = this;

    Login ();
}

public void ShowMainPage ()
{   
    MainPage = new MainPage ();
}

public async void Login ()
{
    await DependencyService.Get<IAuth0WidgetLogin>().LoginUseAuth0EmbeddedWidget();
    App.Current.Properties["IsLoggedIn"] = true;

    ShowMainPage ();
}
```

Hence upon login, I initially I'm not loading any page except the Auth0 Login Widget. Upon the successful login I would like to display the MasterDetailPage. But am getting the following error :
*Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.*

Please advise if I need to load the Widget in an NavigationPage and how to do so.

EDIT 17/7 :

```
public class MenuPage : ContentPage
    {
        MasterDetailPage master;

        TableView tableView;

        public MenuPage ()
        {
            Title = "LoginPattern";
            Icon = "slideout.png";

            var section = new TableSection () {
                new TextCell {Text = "Sessions"},
                new TextCell {Text = "Speakers"},
                new TextCell {Text = "Favorites"},
                new TextCell {Text = "Room Plan"},
                new TextCell {Text = "Map"},
            };

            var root = new TableRoot () {section} ;

            tableView = new TableView ()
            { 
                Root = root,
                Intent = TableIntent.Menu,
            };

            var logoutButton = new Button { Text = "Logout" };
            logoutButton.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
                App.Current.Logout();
            };

            Content = new StackLayout {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Gray,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Children = {
                    tableView, 
                    logoutButton
                }
            };
        }


    }


public class DetailPage : ContentPage
{
    public DetailPage ()
    {
        BackgroundColor = new Color (0, 0, 1, 0.2);

        var text = "Slide > to see the master / menu";

        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android) {
            text = @"Click the action bar dots to see the master / menu";
        } else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone) {
            text = @"Click button \/ to see the master / menu ";
        }

        Content = new StackLayout { 
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Padding = new Thickness (10, 40, 10, 10),
            Children = {

                new Label { Text = text }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It has something to do with the sizing calculation in the slideout menu on Android if I recall correctly. Can you post code for your MenuPage?

Comment: @WilliamCorncobDecker MenuPage and DetailPage code added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try doing two things:

1. Setting the MainPage of your Application to a blank page (or something like a splash page) before you attempt to display the authentication widget.
2. Setting an explicit width request on your MenuPage.

Answer (score 1):

Just for assistance to others, following is my final solution :

```
public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPage ()
    {
        Master = new MenuPage (this);
        Detail = new DetailPage ();
        ShowLoginDialog ();
    }

    async void ShowLoginDialog()
    {
        var page = new LoginPage();

        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);

        App.Current.Login ();
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
}
```

PS: LoginPage is just an empty ContentPage.